# Использование одного RoboSpice сервиса двумя Activity c реакцией на методы жизненного цикла

Tags: java, android, android-service, robospice

**Дано:**

1. Две `Activity` **А** и **В**; **B** стартует из **А**, к **А** возвращаемся из **В**
2. В каждой активити по фрагменту **С**. Фрагмент один и тот же в каждой активити.
3. Фрагменты пользуют один и тоот же `RoboSpice` сервис для хождения в интернеты. Запускают его в `onStart` и останавливают в `onStop`

**Проблема:**

При переходе от одной активити к другой сначала стартует запускаемая активити и только потом останавливается старая. Засим сервис останавливается и результат его работы теряется.

**Возможные решения:**

1. Создать разные сервисы для разных активити.
2. Проверять в `onStop`, что мы запустили другую активити, а не прибиты системой/свёрнуты путём установки флага в активити, из коей запускаем другую.

**Вопрос:**

Оба придуманных мною варианта попыхивают *костылями*. Как таки лучше поступать в такой ситуации?